# AOSP: Custom system service communicating with other services

Tags: android, android-source

I am investigating about a custom system service for AOSP to provide a basic remote control (switching users and starting apps) for the system via network. It should be based on Android 9. For future portability, I would prefer to use rather high-level Java APIs, if possible.

I don't have much knowledge about Android yet on system level. It seems, at least a part of the functionality can be covered by communicating with the Activity Manager, which could be a good starting point.

Some of my questions:

- is it intended at all, to have different system services to communicate with each other?
- Provided this is possible, how can one system service use other service's functionality? Should this still go through HIDL/binder although all services live in the same process?
- Is there an existing system service which does something similiar that could be useful as reference?

Answer (score 4):

> is it intended at all, to have different system services to communicate with each other?

Yes, that is intended.

> Provided this is possible, how can one system service use other service's functionality? Should this still go through HIDL/binder although all services live in the same process?

`HIDL` over `/dev/hwbinder` is intended for HAL to System Service communication. Communication between System Services can still be done with `AIDL` over `/dev/binder`. I think you would typically use a services `Manager` class which will abstract Binder use anyway. This might not be a nice minimalistic example, but you have a look at how the Car service uses the `TelephonyManager` in [CarAudioService.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/+/refs/heads/pie-release/service/src/com/android/car/CarAudioService.java).

> Is there an existing system service which does something similiar that could be useful as reference?

You can have a look at the additional services in [packages/services](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/).

Answer (score 1):

There are two type of system services:
 1. Running in system_server: they are started in [SystemServer.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/7d276c3/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java); apps can call them by XXXManager(eg, ActivityManager); and they also provide some internal api which called by other services in system_server.
 2. Running in apps which have system uid or platform permission: they are normal app [services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services); they can do something that third app can't do; they are complied with android source, so then can call hide api.

Type 2 services can meet most needs. So I suggest you to choose Type 2 service. It's more easier to debugged and maintained.

Comment: Good Point indeed! Can such an app run a service that is safe from the OOM killer and app standby?

Comment: Add android:persistent="true" to avoid killed by low memory killer. See  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.

Comment: Some app is whitelisted for app standby. See this check isAppSpecial : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/services/usage/java/com/android/server/usage/AppStandbyController.java#1007